# Documentation on developing a payment method for opencart?

Tags: module, documentation, payment-gateway, payment, opencart

The information on developing your own payment method (or any module at all) on the opencart site is rather sparse. Is there better information on this topic anywhere else?

Comment: Out of interest what Payment gateway are you trying for?

Comment: In Germany (and maybe Austria) direct debit (Lastschriftverfahren) is pretty common for subscriptions but there is no payment method for that in the current OC version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not something that is documented at all. My advice would be to copy the files from a previous payment gateway such as PayPal standard or pro and build on that, or download a free payment gateway and work from the files in that

Comment: I suspected that. I will try going that route, but it is actually pretty ugly because OCs "API" is incidental this way. The used functions and structures might change without notice. No way to know if the use of some OC piece in the copied module is actually a hack or an official part of the API.

Comment: @EricSchaefer - True, OpenCart lacks the SOLIDITY here whereas Magento would require solid development within the solid MVC of Magento following everything to the Magento API to the bone - but also that is a beauty of OpenCart that you can quickly make fast hacks within the MVC environment using functions and declarations and tpl edits. Magento is not as simple as that. But this is good for some, bad for others.

Comment: @EricSchaefer - You can code the payment gateway as you wish really. There's no hard and fast set rules as to how you do it. However, you should note that the methods the payment gateway(s) call outside of the controller are pretty much standard code (such as the confirm method of the model/checkout/order.php file) so as long as you use them you should be fine for the foreseeable future